# Is the header contact information coded into css file of my wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, header, wordpress-theming, header-files

Not a coder but know so basic html and have built my own out of box wordpress website. I'm helping my dad edit details on this website. We cannot get an answer from original web developer who built this site. I've been able to change the contact details everywhere except for in the header. Its the Karma theme which is different from what I used before. On my own website there's an option to edit Header via the Theme >Customizer and the Appearance>Header section but there's no header section under either appearance or custimizer for this theme in wordpress. I did find a Header section under "Site Options" but nothing has been filled in. I also attempted to amend this via inspector and it allowed me to amend but as soon as I refreshed the page it reverted back to the old contact details.

website: http://www.roofingcontractordublin.com/

Please note you might get a security message for website as we've yet to purchase security cert.
Any tips or suggestions are very welcome as I feel I'm spending far too much time on something someone else could do in a minute or two. Thank you in advance!

Code from section I'm trying to edit:

````
Phone: <a href="tel:015356254">01 5356254</a><br>
Mobile: <a href="tel:0871784746">087 1784746</a><br>
Email: <a href="mailto:smroofingcontractors@gmail.com" style="color:white; text-decoration:none;">smroofingcontractors@gmail.com</a>
<!--/close phone contact --></div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the information could be in either:

1). Widgets, which you should definitely checkout.

2). Maybe hardcoded in the code. That could make things a little bit more complicated but you could start by opening the project in a IDE and searching for that in the code.